# Why does this line of code gets executed even if the conditional returns false?

Tags: yii

perhaps someone could help me here. I have those lines of code:

```
1 $(document).ready(function(){
2 if('<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->action->id?>' == 'update'){
3   if('<?php echo Yii::app()->user->id;?>' != '<?php echo $model->createUser->id; ?>'){
```

I'm getting,

> trying to access property of a non-object (on line 3).

And it makes sense, because I have no object with that property here.

The problem is that the second `if` is running, even if, the first `if` condition returns FALSE.

`Yii::app()->controller->action->id` is NOT equal to 'update' so, the second IF shouldn't NEVER execute. So, I don't understand.

Can anyone please clarify whats going on here plz ?

Cheers

Comment: should I provide more details?

Comment: from your last comment in ernie's answer, what exactly do you want to avoid?

Comment: please comment here. the error gets to the browser because YII_DEBUG and YII_TRACE_LEVEL are enabled in the entry script of the app, i.e _index.php_ in your app's root directory, check that to confirm for yourself.

Comment: try and get your understanding of the web application flow/lifecycle more clear

Comment: @bool.dev any web source regarding the subject?

Comment: none that i know of, but i'm sure a google search will return some results. it is just that you should know it. your last comment in ernie's answer has me confused, i.e i'm not sure if you got this concept of php - javascript execution correctly, which is **very important** for web development!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP will always evaluate, because that's happening server side, while the Javascript is going to execute on client side.  By the time the code gets to the browser, the PHP has all been evaluated and replaced, leaving just Javascript.  Put another way, all the PHP in your view is going to be evaluated (probably by the PHP interpreter in Apache), and the Javascript won't matter until the code runs in the browser.

You need to separate your server-side and client-side code.

Your code is failing server side, since all the PHP has to evaluate to render the Javascript, and in this case, the third PHP block:

```
<? if(isset($model)) echo $model->createUser->id; ?>
```

Looks like when the PHP is running, $model has been set, just not to the expected object.

Comment: so, let's see if I get this. The problem is due to my server-side and client-side incomprehension ? Since php will get evaluated FIRST, it will ignore the javascript part, HENCE, it will ALWAYS run, regardless the javascript conditionals. is that it ?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it . . . for an example, look at one of your working pages in a web browser where you used PHP within a Javascript code block and then view-source on it.  You should see that all the PHP code is gone, and just the values it's evaluated to are there.

Comment: Argh, haven't had my coffee yet . . . actually, you need to put 'echo' calls on all your PHP blocks, or the javascript will actually have nothing in it between the quotes.

Comment: @ernie do you mean, this line: `if(isset($model)´ will never be executed because it has no echo ? Lost with your last comment sorry.

Comment: It will get executed but won't output anything. Items like: <?= Yii::app()->controller->action->id?> will never render anything . . . same as if you just put that code in the view, nothing will show, instead you would need to do a <?= echo Yii::app()->controller->action->id ?>

Comment: @MEM what ernie is saying is that your first `if` is javascript then your second `if` is also javascript, so those will not get evaluated until they reach the client browser. But your third `if` is php and that will get evaluated in your server before reaching the client, and that `if` will obviously fail as you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: @bool.dev actually, if on the third if, I change it to echo instead of isset, I still get the issue. So either all three are javascript and we should see those messages, OR none of them are. :s

Comment: @ernie - your answer doesn't work. <?= echo (it's invalid php) :(

Comment: @bool.dev - I've removed the third if to avoid confusion. No need for it. So, if the php gets executed, we get those values printed on a html + javascript page, but, since PHP get's executed first, it will do whatever it will do, regardless our javascript conditionals - right ? What should we do in order to avoid it then ?

Comment: NO NO NO ! This error gets to the browser, while PHP or APACHE is still executing. Regardless any document ready or not. So all this makes sense. The only issue is related with the isset that should be there. I rest my case.

Comment: Ugh, I really didn't have my coffee (not to mention my not using the short form that often)

<?= is equivalen to <?php echo, so the echo is already there . . . sorry for the confusion/churn - fixed the answer to remove all that . . . in any case, root cause is server-side v. client-side